# BigQuery Error - Loading Timestamp from CSV

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to load a CSV from GCS which contains timestamps in one of the columns.

When I upload via BQ interface, I get the following error:

```
Could not parse '2018-05-03 10:25:18.257000000' as DATETIME for field creation_date (position 6) starting at location 678732930 with message 'Invalid datetime string "2018-05-03 10:25:18.257000000"'
```

Is the issue here the trailing 0's? How would I fix the issue using Python?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct. The issue is the trailing 0s. [DATETIME](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#datetime_type) field only allows 6 digits at the subsecond value.

> Name | Range
>
> DATETIME | 0001-01-01 00:00:00 to 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999

To remove the trailing 0s, you can use Pandas to convert it to a proper DATETIME format so it can be used in BigQuery. For testing purposes, I used a CSV file that contains a dummy value at column 0 and DATETIME with trailing 0s at column 1.

```
Test,2018-05-03 10:25:18.257000000
Test1,2018-05-03 10:22:18.123000000
Test2,2018-05-03 10:23:18.234000000
```

Using this block of code, Pandas will convert column 1 to the proper DATETIME format:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv",header=None) #define your CSV file here
first_column = df.iloc[:, 1] # Change to the location of your DATETIME column
df.iloc[:, 1] = pd.to_datetime(first_column,format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') # convert to correct datetime format
df.to_csv("data.csv", header=False, index=False) # write the new values to data.csv
print(df) #print output for testing
```

This will result to:

```
Test,2018-05-03 10:25:18.257
Test1,2018-05-03 10:22:18.123
Test2,2018-05-03 10:23:18.234
```

You can now use the updated CSV file to write to BQ via BQ interface. See result of BQ testing:

[image]